# Get an end users list of files in google drive

Tags: javascript, api, google-drive-api

So i feel like im missing something here.  I have been to websites before where i can click a button which opens a popup, authorize my account for google, select a file from google drive, then upload it to the website (or at least it appears this way).  Now im looking through documentation and everything i see wants MY api creds.  I want to use the end users though.

My goal is to have the end user pick a file from their google drive, get that url, then store it so they can have a link to view it in THEIR drive account in another window.  I dont want it in MY drive account so why does it appear i need api creds? It really doesnt need ME to have a drive account at all.  Am i searching the wrong stuff here?  How can this be done?

To add:  This will be for a front-end web app (javascript).

Comment: Will your app be a local app (install in the computer) or a web application? The app will be used for any user in the web (that authorizes the app) or for users inside your Workspace account?

Comment: Web application.  For any users that is on my site.

Comment: You're going to need to implement the OAuth user authentication & authorization process, so that other people can grant your app access to their account/their drive. https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview

Comment: So I have to access a google drive from another google drive?  There's no way to just access a users data directly, after they OAuth and give their permission?  Seems like an unnecessary step :/

Comment: Not really, when you use OAuth, the users authorize access to their Google Drive using your web ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your question, I think the one that explains the most what you want to accomplish is this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/picker)

> The Google Picker is a "File Open" dialog for information stored on Google servers. You can use the Google Picker API to allow users to open or upload Google Drive files.

[image: Display the Google Picker]

You can also review more information about the Google Picker API [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview) and a code sample [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample).

> The setOAuthToken function allows an app to use the current auth token to determine which Google Account the Google Picker uses to display the files. If a user is signed in with multiple Google Accounts, the Google Picker can display the files of the appropriate authorized account.

Since you want to use a web application (users from your website,) you will need to create a [GCP project](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project), enable the API for `Google Drive` & `Google Picker API` under `Library`.

[image: Library]

You can search it like this:

[image: search API library]

After that, you will need to set up a [OAuth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent).

[image: OAuth consent screen]

And set it up as `External`.

[image: External]

Create an API key using that project.

[image: API key]

Also, you will need to authorize credentials for a web application, since you want the users of your website to authorize access to their Google Drive to select the files.

[image: web app OAuth]

**Reference:**

- [Display the Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/picker)
- [The Google Picker API overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview)
- [Google Picker code sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)
- [API-specific authorization and authentication information](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth)

Comment: Wow amazing write-up!  Thank you so much!  Im still bummed out that I need to have a google account myself to interact with the end users files, but this is definitely the way to go.  I didnt even see the google picker as an option before.  Amaze-balls

Comment: Im familiar.  Waiting to see if someone has a better solution where I dont need a GCP Project